# Stairwell ceiling fan direction for non-heated or cooled entryway

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have a stairwell ceiling fan about 18 feet above a non-heated or cooled entryway foyer. I'm confused about how to set the direction for winter or summer. The main living area above is heated and cooled.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea is

## Air blowing down = cool

Largely this is a felt effect, because the air is moving over you, i.e. [wind chill](https://www.weather.gov/ama/windchill)

> Wind Chill is a term used to describe what the air temperature feels like to the human skin due to the combination of cold temperatures and winds blowing on exposed skin. In simple terms, the colder the air temperature and the higher the wind speeds the colder it will feel on your skin if you're outside. So even if it remains the same temperature, but the wind speed increases it will actually feel colder to your skin.

## Air blowing up = warm

Hot air rises. Pulling colder air up and out pushes it off the ceiling and towards the walls and down. Because you don't feel the effects of the air movement directly it doesn't add to the chill effect. This one has less noticeable effect because it's trying to mix the air. It's also greatly influenced by how much insulation your ceiling has (less insulation = less heat for the fan to push). Still, it's better than nothing if you're looking to milk efficiency. It's also less effective in larger rooms, where the walls are not close enough to help force the hot air down.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve never considered how to temper adjacent non-heated/cooled space.

If the ceiling/floor is insulated, there is little effect...more if uninsulated.

I think the basic concept that applies is that, “heat rises”.

HEATING MODE

If you’re heating a living space above the room with a fan, then the fan should be turned OFF so the air in the fan-room can rise without being mixed to a cooler temperature.

COOLING MODE

If you’re cooling a living space above the room with a fan, the blades should be turned on so the cooler air is drawn up to the ceiling. In reality, I don’t think it matters much which way the blades rotate. It doesn’t matter if the cool air is drawn UP or the warm air is pushed DOWN. In reality, the air in the room will be “mixed” so there won’t be an advantage to having “cooler” air against the ceiling, because the temperature of the air at the ceiling will be approximately the same as the temperature at the floor.